# Are overlapping language proficiencies wasted?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, proficiency, languages

When creating a character, if you would receive the same skill/tool proficiency from multiple sources, you get to choose another skill/tool proficiency instead of having it go to waste.
Does the same thing apply to languages?

For example, does a Dragonborn Sorcerer who chooses the Draconic archetype know Common, Draconic, and one language he gets to choose? Or just Common and Draconic?

Comment: Your question says that you get to choose another proficiency for skills and tools - could you clarify where the rules say that?

Comment: @MagRoader It's under Backgrounds.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just Common and Draconic.

From Page 123, under Languages, languages are dictated strictly by race, class, and background. It gives no mention to possibly choosing a different language if you already know one, nor does it say anything similar on page 125, where your reference to skills / tools comes from.

While you could add a house rule that would not be game breaking, there isn't a great reason behind a Dragonborn Sorcerer knowing another language just because. Both sources of Draconic are very heavily going to train just the language Draconic, and the experience can't be easily shifted to a different language. Flavorwise, if you went this route, I would encourage something like "You more naturally came into your sorcerer powers as you already knew Draconic, so in your free time you studied [Insert extra language here]"

Answer (score 1):

For class features that overlap with race features, I'd think not.

However, if it were an overlap with background features, I would say yes. On page 125 it says that you can feel free to swap out any language or tool proficiencies from one background for any other language or tool proficiencies.  For example, if your background granted you proficiency with the disguise kit, and you planned on taking the Rogue's Assassin archetype, you could feel free to swap out the disguise kit proficiency for something else.