# Triton Racial and Storm Sorc Class traits duplicate - looking for alternative

Tags: dnd-5e

a player at my table has decided to play a Triton Storm Sorcerer.
Tritons get to speak Common and **Primordial**.
On the other hand, a Storm Sorcerer's Wind Speaker also gets the **Primordial** language at level one.

I would like to give that player another feature to compensate. A different  language would make sense here, but which one would be thematically fitting? Or if not a language, would you suggest another trait that would fit with that class/race combo?

Thank you in advance and happy gaming!

Comment: Hi DYordanov, welcome to the site. Check out the [tour](/tour) to get your second badge. SE is designed for single questions that can have a single best answer. This question seems very open ended, and might be a better fit for a discussion forum or our [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=rpg.stackexchange.com).

Comment: related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47840/are-overlapping-language-proficiencies-wasted